# Email newsletter not working on homepage footer

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter, footer

I used a custom static block to put newsletter subscribe at homepage footer:

```
<div class="bottom_blocks_subscribe">
   {{block type="core/template" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}
<div>
```

After entering a email address and press submit it just redirects to homepage. No entry is added to Newsletter Subscribers. Any ideas what the issue is and how to fix?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Magento Newsletter form not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965410/magento-newsletter-form-not-working)

Try

```
{{block type="newsletter/subscribe" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}
```

The form need to be posted to `newsletter/subscriber/new` which is define in

> Mage_Newsletter_Block_Subscribe

```
/**
 * Retrieve form action url and set "secure" param to avoid confirm
 * message when we submit form from secure page to unsecure
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getFormActionUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('newsletter/subscriber/new', array('_secure' => true));
}
```

Comment: Do you know what the php equivalent of this is?

Comment: +Omar `<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('newsletter/subscribe')->setTemplate('newsletter/subscribe.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>` if the block hasn't been added in the layout XML. You can always put it in the layout XML like this `<block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="footer.newsletter" as="footer.newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml" before="-" />` and then call it like this `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer.newsletter'); ?>`